# Extract string between braces but exclude some

Tags: javascript, regex

Given Input:

```
{abcd} {{abcd}} {{{abcd}}}
```

How can I extract texts which are surrounded by either single braces or triple braces? I don't text if double braces surround it.

Output:

```
{abcd} {abcd}
```

**The second {abcd} in the output is extraced from {{{abcd}}}**

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you just need to extract what's inside and input is always like your sample, it's probably enough to just verify the closing braces: [`[^}{]+(?=}(?:}})?(?!}))`](https://regex101.com/r/lZqmri/4)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use regex to define the pattern.

#### Logic

- Start looking for pattern if `{` or `{{{` is either start of string or is preceded by space.
- Capture any string until `}` or `}}}`

You will have to use non-capturing(`?:`) groups to define the start and end.

```js
var str = '{abcd} {{efgh}} {{{ijkl}}}';
var regex = /(?:^| )(?:\{|\{{3})(\w+)(?:\}|\}{3})/g

console.log(str.match(regex))
```

#### References:

- [What is a non-capturing group in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions)
- [Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/v5ABwi/1): You can refer this to have more depth info as well as to play with inputs/ regex.

Comment: **Note:** If you think there is anything *inaccurate/ missing*, please share your views along with your vote. Also, There can be better a regex using boundaries(`\b`) but not sharing as even I have little knowledge in it.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a non-regEx solution, please check this out. I have tried to make it as simple and extensive as possible using common JS methods like: [Array.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) and [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
function textExtractor(input, startChar, endChar, count, ignoreFlag) {
  let startExpression = new Array(count).fill(startChar).join("");
  let endExpression = new Array(count).fill(endChar).join("");
  if (ignoreFlag) return input;
  else return input.split(startExpression)[1].split(endExpression)[0];
}

console.log(textExtractor("{abc}", "{", "}", 1, false));
console.log(textExtractor("{{abc}}}", "{", "}", 2, true));
console.log(textExtractor("{{{abc}}}", "{", "}", 3, false));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not obsessed with performance, doing it in 2 `.replaces()` makes it very easy :

```
"{abcd} {{abcd}} {{{abcd}}}".replace(/(\s|^){{\w+}}/g,'').replace(/{{({\w+})}}/g, '$1')
```

1st step `replace(/(\s|^){{\w+}}/g,'')` removes {{ }} elements

2nd step `replace(/{{({\w+})}}/g, '$1')` transforms {{{ }}} to { }

Comment: I don't want to remove {{ }} I just want to replace these { } {{{ }}}

Comment: You told us that things like {{abcd}} should be removed because you want to keep only items like  {abcd} and {{{abcd}}}, so this is what my code does:
if you try to execute "{test1} {{test2}} {{{test3}}}".replace(/(\s|^){{\w+}}/g,'').replace(/{{({\w+})}}/g, '$1') then you will get this output: "{test1} {test3}"